# Issue printing header using Rust's CSV crate

Tags: csv, rust, csv-header

Here is my setup:

1. I am reading a csv file, the path to which is passed into the built exe as an argument, and I am using the crate [Clap](https://crates.io/crates/clap) for it.
2. It all reads the file with no problem, but I am having trouble printing the headers.
3. I'd like to be able to print the headers without the quotes, but when I print it, only the first header/column gets printed without them, and the remaining ones do not.
4. Here's what I mean:

This is the part of the code that prints the header:

```
let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_path(file)?;

let column_names = rdr.headers();

println!("{}", match column_names {
        Ok(v) => v.as_slice(),
        Err(_) => "Error!"
});
```

With this, this is what the output is:

```
warning: `csv_reader` (bin "csv_reader") generated 2 warnings
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.13s
     Running `target\release\csv_reader.exe -f C:\nkhl\Projects\dataset\hw_25000.csv`
Index "Height(Inches)" "Weight(Pounds)"
()
```

As you can see, *Index* does not get printed with the quotes, which is how I'd like the others to be printed. Printing with Debug marker enabled, I get this:

```
let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_path(file)?;

let column_names = rdr.headers();

println!("{:?}", match column_names {
        Ok(v) => v.as_slice(),
        Err(_) => "Error!"
});
```

```
warning: `csv_reader` (bin "csv_reader") generated 2 warnings
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 1.92s
     Running `target\release\csv_reader.exe -f C:\nkhl\Projects\dataset\hw_25000.csv`
"Index \"Height(Inches)\" \"Weight(Pounds)\""
()
```

The CSV can be found here: [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/hw_25000.csv](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/csv/hw_25000.csv)

This is how it looks:

```
"Index", "Height(Inches)", "Weight(Pounds)"
1, 65.78331, 112.9925
2, 71.51521, 136.4873
3, 69.39874, 153.0269
```

I hope I am doing something utterly silly, but for the life of me, I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: My apologies. I will change it now. It was just the outputs and not the code itself that I pasted the images of.

Comment: Anything that can read CSV knows what to do with the quotes. It's a bit like complaining that an HTML writer outputs `&quot;` somewhere instead of `"`. They have exactly the same semantic meaning. It's likely escaping anything except alphanumeric characters with quotes as this can make the file less likely to confuse other parsers that may try to e.g. infer the separator character.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `clap` I've never seen anyone use it to parse csv, also you never define `column_names` anywhere in your snippets.

Comment: OK @cafce25 - I've removed the images. I hope now it's easier to read.

Comment: @cafce25 - Yes I am using clap. FYI, it prints to rows and everything just fine, so the arguments are being passed around just fine, so yes, I am pretty sure Clap is what I am using. 

And I've added `column_names` now. Sorry about that.

Comment: None of the code shown uses clap, clap is not a csv parsing library, I say your using clap is unrelated.

Comment: @cdhowie - So are you saying that it's expected behaviour, that when you print `StringRecord`, which `column_names` is, somehow, the first element is not quoted and the other elements are?

Comment: @AnonymousPerson The first element does not contain any non-alphanumeric characters. Try throwing a `(` in it like the other two have, I bet it'll become quoted.

Comment: @cafce25 - OK, yes that's unrelated, which is why I also did not tag my question with it. I thought I should have pointed it out though.

Comment: @cdhowie - I have not tried _that_, but I have tried removing the braces, and that hadn't changed anything. Let me try what you suggested real quick.

Comment: @cdhowie - that didn't work unfortunately, meaning, only the first element was without quotes - Just as before. I'll paste the output in a bit, not at a computer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your csv data contains extraneous spaces after the commas, because of that Rusts `csv` thinks that the quotes around `Height(Inches)` are part of the header, not meant to escape them.
Unfortunately the lack of standardization around csv makes both interpretations valid.

You can use `trim` to get rid of the extra spaces:

```rust
let data: &[u8] = include_bytes!("file.csv");
let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new().trim(csv::Trim::All).from_reader(data);
```

But csv does the unquoting before it applies the `trim` so this does still leave you with the same problem.
You can additionaly disable `quoting` to at least get the same behaviour on all columns:

```rust
let mut rdr = csv::ReaderBuilder::new().quoting(false).trim(csv::Trim::All).from_reader(data);
```

If you somehow can remove the spaces from your csv file it works just fine:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data: &[u8] = br#""Index","Height(Inches)","Weight(Pounds)"
1,65.78331,112.9925
2,71.51521,136.4873
3,69.39874,153.0269"#;
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_reader(data);
    let hd = rdr.headers().unwrap();
    println!("{}", hd.as_slice());
    // prints `IndexHeight(Inches)Weight(Pounds)` without any `"`
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a8a5d5a35a81ede8246be327869be039)

Comment: The output `"Index \"Height(Inches)\" \"Weight(Pounds)\""` seems to imply this isn't the case, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: `"Index \"Height(inches)\" \"Weight(Pounds)\""` is the concatenation of `"Index"`, `" \"Height(Inches)\""` and `" \"Weight(Pounds)\""` the values wich `csv` thinks are the headers.

Comment: @cdhowie you can check the now working playground link to see it for yourself.

Comment: The playground is not loading for me right now.

Comment: @cdhowie I've added the code from the playground here as well.

Comment: Yes, `quoting(false)` did the trick. Thanks for the help.